Can't shift bits in a loop
I'm trying to make a program that shifts bits that go outside the range back to 0. I encountered this problem:

where it just prints out the same 3 sets of bits and ignores the changes that happen after the conditions for the loop are met.
However, if I use the << operator outside the loop, it works just fine here:

results for the 1st example. It seems that .set(), .test(), and other operators work perfectly fine except '<<'.
tried: do and ternary

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Post the sourcecode and not a picture of it if you want to get answers to your question. Also take a look at the tour and the guide to how to ask a good question. You might also want to step through your code in a debugger to find the fault.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Your IDE tries to tell you something when you write
(xd << 1);

In fact, this instruction doesn't change xd in your loop.  Try instead with
xd = xd << 1;   // or if you like it short xd <<= 1;

